# Tridion - Placing Item in Workflow from Event

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Is it possible to place an item in workflow from the event system?  The problem I am facing is that we would like to direct components to two different workflows based on what folder they are in (instead of what schema they use), which the Tridion UI doesn't seem to support.  I was hoping to write an event that is triggered on check-in of a component, so I can then determine which folder that component is in and direct it into the appropriate workflow from the event.

I'm fine with creation of the event, I'm just totally lost on where to start as far as adding the item to workflow goes.  I have looked at the TOM.NET API documentation but really haven't found anything that helps.  Any assistance or examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Jeremy suggests, what you are actually trying to do is not possible.

However you can achieve the same outcome by making the second step of your workflow an automated decision which  creates 2 separate workflow branches within one workflow process definition. Your automated decision can read the Org Item of the component and direct it accordingly.

Comment: Interesting approach, useful to know. Do you check who performed the initial save and assign the next manual activity to them?

Comment: Thank you both.  I will give Chris' suggestion a try.

Comment: You can only do this with a manual decision - you can't save the process to Tridion if the first activity is an automatic decision.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible - a Component is only added to a WF process when it is saved and its Schema has an associated process definition.